# Should you let a potential employer know about another opportunity you have to help accomodate?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, time-management, research

So that question may sound a bit weird, but it's a bit of a complicated situation. So recently I was landed an offer by the math department at my college to work on a special research program over the next year. The program is no-joke, and I would most likely end up published, and I would be paid a fairly large amount.

However, I also am interviewing currently at a company that is practically my dream job. The Math department would like an answer by the end of the semester, but the next round of interviews for the company is happening in early February. I would love to take the research position, but I know I would rather the internship, should I be selected.

Should I inform the company of my situation? What would be the best method to go about it?

Comment: This *might* be a better fit for academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: @EthanTheBrave I think this is more workplace related, as OP is talking about a job and not some academic task. But it is academic related, undoubtedly.

Comment: When is "the end of the semester"? If the interviews are only happening 2 months from now, it doesn't sound much like something that can be moved, especially when it's for just an internship (but that's not to say you can't just tell them about it if the alternative is just declining without giving a reason).

Comment: End of semester is around December 20th, so this will be happening about 1 month after the Math department wants me to respond. I know they are willing to work with me, but it is quite a long time

Answer (score 4):

> Should I inform the company of my situation? What would be the best method to go about it?

**I would not.** This could be a risky move, as saying that may cause them to think twice about your candidacy for the job. You would have better chances of successfully using this as a vantage point on your negotiation *if* the next round of interviews were earlier.

Seems that this is a problem of timing and deciding, so I think that the best thing to do is that you make your mind on what you really want. Would you take this job as a "safe" move, or would you rather reject this offer with the hopes of *possibly* landing that dream job?

After that you can decide what you value more, and focus your efforts on that one.

---

On a more unofficial note:

From what I can perceive of you situation **maybe** what is best for you is to **take the research job.** Not only you say you are going to be paid a really good amount, but you will also be publishing a research, something quite invaluable for certain job and Academic applications.

Surely after that your "dream job" would be more likely to be interested in your profile, giving you better chances to land that (or similar) positions in the future.

Comment: But do not string them along and then leave them hanging, or reneg on the commitment if something better comes along, for sure. If the other one is that much of a priority, then OP should turn down the research position.  +1

Comment: @PoloHoleSet yes. After making up his mind, OP should be clear with both sides. This is the professional approach regardless of what he decided (also helps to keep doors open for future chances).